# How to generate new route to the new stfull widget when user created new container?

Tags: flutter

I am currently developing an app which people can save their receipt in it, I shared home screen below,initial time It will be empty, as soon as user add  new menu, it will get full with menu, After user added new menu, the should be able to click the menu container, and access to new screen for example, İn home screen I created container which called "CAKES", the cakes screen should be created, if I created another menu in my home screen It should also created too, I currently menu extanded screen as a statefull widget already, you can see below, but my question is How can I create this page for spesific menu's , How can I store them, in list, in map etc, Lastly, I dont want user information dissapear, I know I have to use database, but I want to use local database, How can I handle with that, Have a nice day...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lezzet_kitabi/add_menu_screen.dart';
import 'package:lezzet_kitabi/constants.dart';
import 'package:lezzet_kitabi/widgets.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({this.newMenuName,this.imagePath});
  final  imagePath;
  final  newMenuName;
  static String id="homeScreen";
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Widget buildBottomSheet(BuildContext context)=>AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route: HomeScreen,);


  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    if (widget.newMenuName!=null && widget.imagePath!=null){
      Widget newMenu=MenuCard(newMenuName: widget.newMenuName,imagePath: widget.imagePath);
      menuCards.insert(0,newMenu);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kColorTheme1,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2C3D4).withOpacity(1),
          title:TitleBorderedText(title:"SEVIMLI YEMEKLER", textColor: Color(0xFFFFFB00)),
          actions: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 27,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(kCuttedLogoPath),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(kBGWithLogoOpacity),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children:menuCards,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow:[
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                            spreadRadius: 2,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: Offset(0,4),
                            ),
                          ],
                        color: kColorTheme7,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      ),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route: "homeScreen",),
                          );
                        },
                        child: TitleBorderedText(title: "LEZZET GRUBU EKLE",textColor: Colors.white,)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:lezzet_kitabi/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:lezzet_kitabi/widgets.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class AddMenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  AddMenuScreen({@required this.buttonText, @required this.route});
  final route;
  final String buttonText;
  static String id="addMenuScreen";
  @override
  _AddMenuScreenState createState() => _AddMenuScreenState();
}

class _AddMenuScreenState extends State<AddMenuScreen> {
  int selectedIndex=-1;
  Color _containerForStickersInactiveColor=Colors.white;
  Color _containerForStickersActiveColor=Colors.black12;
  final stickerList= List<String>.generate(23, (index) => "images/sticker$index");
  String chosenImagePath;
  String menuName;
  int addScreenImageNum;


  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    createAddScreenImageNum();
  }

  void createAddScreenImageNum(){
    Random random =Random();
    addScreenImageNum = random.nextInt(3)+1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: kColorTheme9,
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40),topLeft: Radius.circular(40)),
          ),
          child:Padding(
            padding:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kColorTheme2,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90)
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily:"Graduate",
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      menuName=value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border:OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Menü ismi belirleyin",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                        fontFamily: "Graduate",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Text(" yana kadırarak menünüz icin bir resim secin",textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Graduate", fontSize: 12),),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: stickerList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: index == selectedIndex ?
                          _containerForStickersActiveColor :
                          _containerForStickersInactiveColor,
                        ),
                        child:FlatButton(
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("images/sticker$index.png"),
                          ),
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex = index;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    color: kColorTheme7,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                  ),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      widget.route=="homeScreen"?Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomeScreen(newMenuName: menuName,imagePath: "images/sticker$selectedIndex.png")))
                              :Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MenuExtension(menuExtensionName: menuName)),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(widget.buttonText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color:  Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "Graduate", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'add_menu_screen.dart';
import 'package:bordered_text/bordered_text.dart';
import 'package:lezzet_kitabi/screens/meal_screen.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

List<Widget> menuExtensionCards=[EmptyMenu()];
List<Widget> menuCards=[EmptyMenu()];

class MenuCard extends StatelessWidget {
  MenuCard({this.newMenuName, this.imagePath});
  final newMenuName;
  final imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MenuExtension(menuExtensionName: newMenuName,)));
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: 180,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    newMenuName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'Graduate',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                        imagePath
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class EmptyMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route:"homeScreen"),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: 180,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,size: 100,color: Colors.grey.shade400,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MenuExtension extends StatefulWidget {
  MenuExtension({this.menuExtensionName});
  final String menuExtensionName;
  @override
  _MenuExtensionState createState() => _MenuExtensionState();
}

class _MenuExtensionState extends State<MenuExtension> {
  Widget buildBottomSheet(BuildContext context)=>AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Tarif Ekle",route: MealScreen,);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2C3D4).withOpacity(1),
          title:BorderedText(
            child:Text(
              widget.menuExtensionName,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0XFFFFFB00),
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: "Graduate"
              ),
            ),
            strokeWidth: 5,
            strokeColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          actions: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 27,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/cuttedlogo.PNG"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/logoBGopacity.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children:menuExtensionCards,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow:[
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                            spreadRadius: 2,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: Offset(0,4),
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: kColorTheme7,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      ),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Tarif Ekle", route:"mealScreen"),
                          );
                        },
                        child: BorderedText(
                          strokeWidth: 5,
                          strokeColor: Colors.black,
                          child:Text("Tarif Ekle",style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily:'Graduate',
                            fontSize:30,
                          ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TitleBorderedText extends StatelessWidget {
  TitleBorderedText({this.title, this.textColor});
  final Color textColor;
  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BorderedText(
      strokeWidth: 5,
      strokeColor: Colors.black,
      child:Text(title,style: TextStyle(
        color: textColor,
        fontFamily:'Graduate',
        fontSize:30,
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? No one here want's to build your app for you.

Comment: I dont want someone build my app for me, I explained my questions detailed, and I shared necessary codes below, My main question is how to create new page for the each container that user created and how can I store that?